# Помогите понять смысл использования битов и побитового сдвига в классе

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Есть проект программы на Java Swing. Я пытаюсь разобраться в её коде. Сам проект представляет из себя игру в шашки.
В ней представлен класс Board, который является представлением размеченной шахматной доски, на которую выставляются шашки разного цвета. Я анализировал код и остановился на этом классе. Я совершенно не понимаю, зачем здесь нужен побитовый сдвиг и другие битовые операции. Я не понимаю, какие функции они выполняют и зачем нужны в коде.

Вот нужный фрагмент:

```
for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i ++) {
        boolean set = ((1 << (state.length - i - 1)) & id) != 0;
        this.state[i] = setBit(state[i], index, set);
```

В этом цикле state.length всегда равен трем, index - индекс клетки от 0 до 32, id - идентификатор типа клетки (пустая/черная шашка/белая шашка)

Вот весь класс:

```
    package model;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Board {

    public static final int INVALID = -1; // Константа, обозначающая некорректное значение
    public static final int EMPTY = 0; // Константа, обозначающая пустое поле
    public static final int BLACK_CHECKER = 4 * 1 + 2 * 1 + 1 * 0; // Константа, обозначающая черную шашку
    public static final int WHITE_CHECKER = 4 * 1 + 2 * 0 + 1 * 0; // Константа, обозначающая белую шашку
    public static final int BLACK_KING = 4 * 1 + 2 * 1 + 1 * 1; // Константа, обозначающая черного короля
    public static final int WHITE_KING = 4 * 1 + 2 * 0 + 1 * 1; // Константа, обозначающая белого короля

    private int[] state; // Массив состояний доски (три элемента)

    // Конструктор класса
    public Board() {
        reset();
    }

    // Создает копию объекта Board
    public Board copy() {
        Board copy = new Board();
        copy.state = state.clone();
        return copy;
    }

    // Метод, сбрасывающий доску в начальное состояние
    public void reset() {

        // Сброс состояния доски
        this.state = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i ++) {
            set(i, BLACK_CHECKER); // На черные клетки в начале игры ставятся черные шашки
            set(31 - i, WHITE_CHECKER); // На белые клетки в начале игры ставятся белые шашки
        }
    }

    // Метод, находящий все фигуры на доске с определенным ID
    public List<Point> find(int id) {

        // Находим все черные клетки с соответствующим ID
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i ++) {
            if (get(i) == id) {
                points.add(toPoint(i));
            }
        }

        return points;
    }

    // Метод, устанавливающий фигуру на доску по координатам
    public void set(int x, int y, int id) {
        set(toIndex(x, y), id);
    }

    // Метод, устанавливающий фигуру на доску по индексу
    public void set(int index, int id) {

        // Выход за границы массива
        if (!isValidIndex(index)) {
            return;
        }

        // Некорректный ID, устанавливаем значение EMPTY
        if (id < 0) {
            id = EMPTY;
        }

        // Устанавливаем биты
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i ++) {
            boolean set = ((1 << (state.length - i - 1)) & id) != 0;
            this.state[i] = setBit(state[i], index, set);
        }
    }

    // Метод получения значения ячейки по координатам
    public int get(int x, int y) {
        return get(toIndex(x, y));
    }

    // Метод получения значения ячейки по индексу
    public int get(int index) {
        if (!isValidIndex(index)) {
            return INVALID;
        }
        // Получение битов состояния в указанном индексе
        return getBit(state[0], index) * 4 + getBit(state[1], index) * 2
                + getBit(state[2], index);
    }

    // Метод преобразования индекса в координаты
    public static Point toPoint(int index) {
        int y = index / 4;
        int x = 2 * (index % 4) + (y + 1) % 2;
        // Если индекс недопустим, возвращаем координаты (-1, -1)
        return !isValidIndex(index)? new Point(-1, -1) : new Point(x, y);
    }

    // Метод преобразования координат в индекс
    public static int toIndex(int x, int y) {

        // Если координаты недопустимы (не на доске или на белой клетке), возвращаем -1
        if (!isValidPoint(new Point(x, y))) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        return y * 4 + x / 2;
    }

    // Метод преобразования объекта Point в индекс
    public static int toIndex(Point p) {
        return (p == null)? -1 : toIndex(p.x, p.y);
    }

    // Метод установки бита в целевом числе
    public static int setBit(int target, int bit, boolean set) {

        // Если номер бита недопустим, ничего не делаем
        if (bit < 0 || bit > 31) {
            return target;
        }

        // Установка бита
        if (set) {
            target |= (1 << bit);
        }
        
        // Очистка бита
        else {
            target &= (~(1 << bit));
        }
        
        return target;
    }

    // Метод получения бита из целевого числа
    public static int getBit(int target, int bit) {

        // Если номер бита недопустим, возвращаем 0
        if (bit < 0 || bit > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        return (target & (1 << bit)) != 0? 1 : 0;
    }

    // Метод нахождения середины отрезка между двумя точками
    public static Point middle(Point p1, Point p2) {

        // Если одна из точек не инициализирована, возвращаем координаты (-1, -1)
        if (p1 == null || p2 == null) {
            return new Point(-1, -1);
        }
        
        return middle(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }

    // Метод нахождения середины отрезка между двумя индексами
    public static Point middle(int index1, int index2) {
        return middle(toPoint(index1), toPoint(index2));
    }

    // Метод для нахождения середины координат между двумя точками на шахматной доске
    public static Point middle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        // Проверка координат
        int dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
        if (x1 < 0 || y1 < 0 || x2 < 0 || y2 < 0 || // Не в пределах доски
                x1 > 7 || y1 > 7 || x2 > 7 || y2 > 7) {
            return new Point(-1, -1);
        } else if (x1 % 2 == y1 % 2 || x2 % 2 == y2 % 2) { // Белая клетка
            return new Point(-1, -1);
        } else if (Math.abs(dx) != Math.abs(dy) || Math.abs(dx) != 2) { // Неправильные шаги
            return new Point(-1, -1);
        }

        return new Point(x1 + dx / 2, y1 + dy / 2);
    }

    // Метод для проверки, является ли индекс действительным
    public static boolean isValidIndex(int testIndex) {
        return testIndex >= 0 && testIndex < 32;
    }

    // Метод для проверки, является ли точка действительной на шахматной доске
    public static boolean isValidPoint(Point testPoint) {

        if (testPoint == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Проверка находится ли точка на доске
        final int x = testPoint.x, y = testPoint.y;
        if (x < 0 || x > 7 || y < 0 || y > 7) {
            return false;
        }

        // Проверка находится ли точка на черной клетке
        if (x % 2 == y % 2) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Метод для получения строкового представления объекта
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String obj = getClass().getName() + "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i ++) {
            obj += get(i) + ", ";
        }
        obj += get(31);

        return obj + "]";
    }
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь в разъяснении.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

1. Рассмотрим константы.
   Состояние поля определяется 3-мя битами.

```
index: 3 2 1
bits : 0 0 0
```

Третий бит отвечает за наличие шашки на поле. 1 - шашка есть, 0 - шашки нет

Второй бит отвечает за цвет шашки. 1 - чёрная, 0 - белая.

Первый бит отвечает за тип шашки. 1 - дамка, 0 - обычная.

2. `new int[3]` создаёт массив из трёх элементов типа int. int - это 32 бита (4 байта). Т.е. 1-го int-а достаточно для хранения двоичного состояния всей доски. (шашечная доска - это 32 клетки, так как используются только белые клетки и чёрные можно отбросить)

Отсюда понятно, что доска представлена в виде трёх слоёв, по int-у на каждый. Первый слой хранит признак, стоит там шашка или нет, второй - цвет шашки, а третий признак дамки.

3. Рассмотрим `set(15, BLACK_CHECKER);`, т.е. `index=15; id=0b110` (на самом деле `index` нам для объяснения не понадобится)

```
for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i ++) {
        boolean set = ((1 << (state.length - i - 1)) & id) != 0;
        this.state[i] = setBit(state[i], index, set);
    }
```

Что тут происходит?
Тут по очереди перебираются слои.

```
i==0
set = ((1 << (3 - 0 - 1)) & 0b110) != 0
set = (1 << 2) & 0b110 != 0
set = 0b100 & 0b110 != 0
set = true

i=1
set = ((1 << (3 - 1 - 1)) & 0b110) != 0
set = (1 << 1) & 0b110 != 0
set = 0b010 & 0b110 != 0
set = true

i=2
set = ((1 << (3 - 2 - 1)) & 0b110) != 0
set = (1 << 0) & 0b110 != 0
set = 0b001 & 0b110 != 0
set = false
```

т.е.

- выставляем бит на первом слое(наличие шашки) в 1 (есть шашка)
- выставляем бит на втором слое(цвет) в 1 (чёрный)
- выставляем бит на третьем слое(дамка) в 0 (обычная шашка)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение! Но у меня осталось несколько вопросов.
Во-первых, почему в алгоритме с перебором слоев автор кода просто не задал true true false, а стал делать это через пересечение битов (операнд &)? Просто захотел?
Во-вторых, насколько вообще целесообразно применение такого варианта с побитовыми операциями? Стоит ли мне углубляться в тему использования таких конструкций для того, что быть способным читать и воспроизводить подобный код или это скорее исключительный пример на реальной практике?
Заранее спассибо!

Comment: 1) Скорее всего просто захотел. Возможно такой подход даёт прирост производительности во время самой игры при просчёте ходов, но это надо смотреть код и запускать бенчмарки. Если же не заморачиваться микрооптимизациями, то самым простым и наглядным решением тут выглядит массив Enum-ов
2) Побитовые операции в проектах на Java - это редкость. Обычно их используют там, где они могут дать значимый прирост производительности и экономию памяти. В ацком хайлоаде каком-нибудь с огромными массивами данных.

Comment: Благодарю вас еще раз.